# How to check for each employee if his/her email matches the searched value

Tags: java, hashmap

Just wondering how i would match user input to the contents of the employee class.

```
public void searchByName ()
{
    //and check for each employee if his/her email matches the searched value
    for(Employee e : map.values())
    {
        System.out.println(e); //Will print out Employee toString().
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of search input? And what does the search input target (email? name?)?

Comment: well for this particular method it would be looking for employeeName.

Comment: `Map` is for exact match (or at most normalized matching). Not sure if there is any better method than looping through all employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you're using a Map of Employees, but assuming that your email address is stored as a String object inside your Employee class, with the appropriate getter `getEmail()`, then the code would look something like this:

```
public Employee findEmail( String email )
{
    for( Employee e : map.values() )
    {
        if( email.equals( e.getEmail() ) )
            return e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This code is not very efficient though, as it will have to loop through every single Employee in your Map.

If, however, your Map contains a mapping of email addresses to Employees, then you can very quickly get the Employee associated with an email address using the Map's `get( Object key )` method:

```
Employee emp = map.get( "someone@somedomain.com" );

if( emp != null )
    System.out.println( "Employee with that email address is " + emp );
else
    System.out.println( "No Employee with that email address." );
```

I hope this helps. As a side note, posting more code (such as your Employee class) would definitely help make solutions more accurate and helpful.